# How do I check for browser support for AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, browser-support

I have to check if the browser being used supports my site which uses AngularJS version 1.2.12. The goal is to show a message saying to 'update/change your browser' for old versions of Chrome/Safari/IE. Feature detection is recommended in general but for issues like this: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4749 where select elements don't refresh their values, as well as some other IE8 issues, feature detection doesn't seem relevant so I'm planning to use:

```
<!--[if IE]>
less than IE10
<![endif]-->
```

Is there an AngularJS way of detecting support for its features? Should I be checking for old versions of Chrome/Safari at all?

Comment: See here : http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie

Comment: The stuff in the guide don't work for the issue that I linked. And the solutions listed in the link work only for IE10 not IE8, at least in my case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In our project we use html conditional comment to detect which version of IE is running. Something among the lines:

```
<!--[if IE 8]><html class="lt-ie9"><![endif]-->
```

You can also use [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) which has feature detection.

In terms of other browsers you should be fine, since they update themselves regularly and we haven't find any particular issue related only to one specific version.

Comment: Do you know if there are features checked by Modernizr that are needed specifically by AngularJS?

Comment: As far as I know AngularJS doesn't need any specific feature from the browser to run properly. You should just be aware of the bugs within the browser (ie. IE8/IE9 not rendering properly when dynamically changing the options of a select element).